# Windows 7 problem of disk space

Tags: windows-7, disk-space, system-restore, pagefile

I bought my new computer a few weeks ago. I have 2 harddrive with 60 GB (C:) and 1TB (D:).
Now my first problem was to free up some space on C as when I bought it with only windows installed there were just 15/20 GB free... I followed some instruction and I changed the settings of the page file, the restore points and so on and I arrived to 30 GB.

Today I upgraded my Windows from Home to Professional and when i checked my C drive the space became suddenly 15 Gb. Anyone know what happened and how can I recover my space agan?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the drive contents with something like [TreeSize Free](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/). This will show you how much room each folder is taking up on C:.

You can move the recycle bin, page file, and the update uninstall files as well.

By the way, what is the model?  Lately I have seen new HP computers that come with a backup utility installed by default that keeps HUGE backups on the C partition without any indication it is doing so.  HP Recovery I think its called... if you have that you can move the backups to D: or uninstall it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have An intel I7-2600k

Comment: Also take a look at [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/).

Answer (score 0):

Likely, when you do an in-place upgrade, it made a backup of your old windows folder. You should be able to safely delete this folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the built in 'Disk Cleanup' (type it into the Start menu search bar), if the OS has temp files left around related to your update it should find them and allow you to clean them up with ease.

[image]